# AD Organization feedback requested

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, groups

I'm taking over an AD domain (not large) administration but it looks like it needs some organization. For example, under the top domain "something.com" there is a folder named "User" with many security and distribution groups that are in use. Mostly global. There is also a folder under the top domain specific to the network named "something office". This is where the rest of the security and distribution groups, computers and user objects are at, all with their own subfolder.

What I would like to get some feedback on is does it really matter where the groups are located as long as policy and permissions work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where the users/groups live only really matter if you are using group policy.  Otherwise they'll work the same no matter where they are.  That said, you should be using group policy, and you'll want that to guide your OU structure and not necessarily mimic your company's organizational structure.

Since you're inheriting this, you should open the Group Policy Management tool to see what is in place now before you move/reorganize anything.

Comment: `Where the users/groups live only really matter if you are using group policy` - Care to explain that? Additionally, you can't have an AD domain without having at least two GPO's in use. `you'll want that to guide your OU structure and not necessarily mimic your company's organizational structure.` - That's your opinion.

Comment: I guess anything in design could be called an opinion, but building your OU structure around what you're doing with it (delegation or GP inheritance) is a better practice than building it to match company org.  If he'd like to look more in OU design, this TechNet article has a few good ways to do it.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.05.oudesign.aspx

Comment: There are several GPO's in use but the only ones involved with the gist of my question involve drive mappings. CIO wants to consolidate and migrate to a common naming convention so I'm looking at just creating new SG's where they need to reside and adding that to the GPO and then puling the old SG's off the GPO when completed. Just not sure it's the smoothest way to go about it.

Comment: The GPO can be applied to multiple OUs, so you could create the final structure you want, apply the appropriate GPOs, then migrate the users as you need.